# JQUERY css class not work on dynamically add div

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery-1.6.2 and drag and drop plugins

following is code in webform1.aspx

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" , helper: "clone" });

    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            addFields( ui.draggable );
        }
    });

});
```

on drop i am calling addfields function which is as follow

```
function addFields($items)
{
    var content=$(".droppable")
    ans_type=$items.attr("id")
    i= parseInt(document.getElementById('txtQCnt').value);
    document.getElementById('txtQCnt').value=i+1;
    $.ajax
    (
        {
            url:'handler.ashx?ans_type='+ans_type+'&cnt='+document.getElementById('txtQCnt').value,
            dataType:'html',
            success: function(data)
            {
                var i;
                content.append(data);
            }
        }
   )
}
```

handler.ashx add the element to the page

```
context.Response.Write("<div id='"+objId+"' class='droppable'></div>");
```

on dynamically add div from handler.ashx, when object being dragged droppable div css class should highlight, which is not working

Comment: you are missing semicolons, `var content=$(".droppable")` and `ans_type=$items.attr("id")`

Comment: You are probably looking for `$.live()` or `$.delegate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to bind the droppable inside the success method -

```
$('.droppable').droppable(options);
```

where you can make the options as constants and define only once.

Else, you can bind live to the element on mouseenter or hover at which the droppable can be attached.

```
$('.droppable').live('mouseenter',function() {
    $(this).droppable(options);
});
```